# What's the difference between mocking an object and just setting a value

Tags: php, unit-testing

I know that me asking this question means that i probably didn't understand mocking fully. I know why using mocks (isolation) , i know how to use mocks (each FW and it's way) - but i don't understand - if the purpose of mocking is to return *expected* value to isolate my unit test, why should i mock an object and not just create the value by myself?

Why this:

```
    $searchEngine = Mockery::mock('elasticSearch');
    $searchEngine->shouldReceive('setupDataConnection')->once()->andReturn("data connected");

    $insertData = new DataInserter;
    $this->assertEquals("data connected",$insertData->insertData($searchEngine));
```

And not this:

```
    $knownResult = "data connected";
    $insertData = new DataInserter;
    $this->assertEquals($insertData->insertData($searchEngine) ,$knownResult);
```

**Edit**
Sorry for the mistake, but the accidently didn't include the insertData in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using a mock you have access to additional information, from a object that behaves directly like a C style struct ( only performs data storage ) then there is little difference (with the exception about making assertions about calls to your mocks that are usually rather useful since you can then make sure that your value is for example set 3 times, and not 7 (maybe with some intermediate value that could cause potential problems. )

Mocks are useful for testing the interactions between objects.

Now if your class does something more complex ( such as access a resource like a database, or read/write data from a file. ) then mocks become lifesaving because they pretty much allow you to abstract away the internal behavior of classes that are not under test (for example lets imagine that the first version of your class simply stores values in memory, the next version stores them in a specific place in a database, this way you can first of all save yourself the resource hit of a database access and secondly be able to effectively prove that your class under test works correctly as opposed to also proving that your data access class works. if you have a failed test then you can hone in on the issue immediately as opposed to trying to have to figure out if the issue is in your data provider or data accessor. )

Because tests can be ran in parallel certain resources can cause false failures.
A few examples of interactions which are extremely difficult to test without mocks would be:

1. Code which talks to a Database Access layer ( ensuring that queries are correct, close() is called on the connection, and appropriate SQL is sent, plus you don't modify a real database. )
2. File/Socket IO (again ensuring that data is consistent)
3. System calls ( e.g. calls to php exec)
4. anything that relies on threads / timing ( not as much of an issue in PHP)
5. GUI Code ( again, almost unheard of in PHP) but if I shift the language to lets say java its significantly easier to call :
   when(myDialogBoxMock).showOptionInputDialog().thenReturn("mockInput")
   then to try to fake it with subclasses or temporary implementations/subclasses.
6. Calls to specific methods which must be called with a specific value only. 
   verify(myMock.setValue(7), times(2));
   verifyNoOtherInteractions(myMock);

A large part of this is also speed, if you are reading a file off the disk lets say 300/400 times in a massive codebase then you will definitely notice a speed increase by using mocks.

If you have a tool like EMMA/jacoco for java in PHP you will be able to have a effective code coverage report to show you where your tests are not covering code. And on any non-trivial application you will find yourself trying to figure out how the hell to get your object under test into a specific state to test specific behavior, Mocks with DI are really your tool to perform these tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you give some real life example to interaction i might need to test between objects that are not testable without using a mock?

Comment: @cmvr I edited the post to provide 6 examples that came to mind immediately.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not sure i understand. If with mockery i can use (for examples) classes that doesn't actually connects to DB (or may not even exist) - how this helps me to verify my queries are correct? Also, if the point of mocking is isolation, why would i want to test my queries in unrelated unit test? Thank you for taking the time to explain and the detailed answer.

Comment: Well if class A calls the DB layer directly (lets say you are using PDO) then by mocking the PDO class then you can assert that the query is correct (by assertations against string passed into pdo and return 'mock data'), These were all just examples really, The entire idea behind mocking is that you are testing class A and its interactions between other classes. If you use 'live objects' then you are testing Classes A, B, and maybe C. The purpose of a unit test is to test a single class. At the end of the day you want 1 Test class for every real class.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are providing a fake collaborator ($searchEngine) for your DataInserter. In the assert statement you are calling insertData, which will execute the logic of your DataInserter that will in term interact with the fake $searchEngine. By providing the fake, you can verify that the logic of DataInserter works correctly in isolation.

In your second example, you are not testing the DataInserter logic. You are just checking whether the constant string $knownResult is equal to "data connected", i.e. you are testing string equality of php. As far as I can see from the snippet you are constructing a new DataInserter object but you aren't even exercising its code in the test.

Comment: Could you post the entire second test? For example, how is the $searchEngine variable initialized?